# Deleting songs on computer from an iTunes playlist

Tags: macos, itunes, music, playlist

Oftentimes, I am in an iTunes playlist and want to delete a song from my computer.

However, if I am in an iTunes playlist, I can only delete the song from the playlist, and then I have to go back to `All Music` in iTunes to delete the song from the computer.

[image]

The picture above shows the window that appears when I go to delete a song in a playlist.

Is there a way to delete a song from a playlist and the computer at the same time?

---

#### Tech Specs

- OS X 10.8.4
- iTunes 11.0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In iTunes, select the song in your playlist and press <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> + <kbd>⌥ alt/option</kbd> + <kbd>← backspace</kbd>.

[image: Do you want to delete the selected song, or keep it in the iTunes Media folder?]

It will prompt you to delete the file from your iTunes Media folder as well as the playlist itself.

---

To do this completely from the keyboard, enable Full Keyboard Access to All Controls (from System Preferences → Keyboard → Shortcuts) to be able to tab to the Delete File button, then press <kbd>Space</kbd> to 'click' it.

Alternatively, you could create an AppleScript or Automator action that runs on a BetterTouchTool shortcut/gesture to do this in one step.

Answer (score 0):

For those using a Windows-based machine with iTunes, you'll want to press CTRL + SHIFT + DEL to delete the songs you've selected from your playlist.  I hope this helps.