# How can I delete song from both playlist and iTunes library?

Tags: itunes

How can I delete a song both from a playlist and the iTunes music library when viewing the playlist in iTunes 12.0.1.26.

I've tried several key combinations with `Backspace` and `Delete` (in the `Edit`menu) is disabled.

Comment: oops - after I answered I found a duplicate question, which actually has a different method, so take your pick - http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99911/deleting-songs-on-computer-from-an-itunes-playlist?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple…

<kbd>Alt ⌥</kbd>  Right Click & you get the option to Delete added to the context menu

[image]

Alternatively - press  <kbd>Cmd ⌘</kbd>   +  <kbd>Alt ⌥</kbd>   + <kbd>← backspace</kbd>
*see* [Deleting songs on computer from an iTunes playlist](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/99911/deleting-songs-on-computer-from-an-itunes-playlist?rq=1)

Comment: Thx also for finding the duplicate question (which I was not aware of). BTW, I am using OS X, so it's Alt-Ctrl Click.

Comment: [alt]/ctrl/click is the same as [alt]/right click for those without a right mouse button. They are functionally identical.